# ICE protocol what is base?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

In ICE protocol, What is Base?

I understood Base as, for the server reflexive candidate , host candidate is the base, is it correct or not?

How to find the foundation of the candidate?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. According RFC5245 :

> Base:  The base of a server reflexive candidate is the **host candidate**
>   from which it was derived.  A host candidate is also said to have a
>   base, equal to that candidate itself.  Similarly, the base of a
>   relayed candidate is that candidate itself.

The foundation is an arbitrary value. You can find it for each ICE candidates in the SDP. It is the first value after `candidate:`

For example

```
a=candidate:1174096638 1 udp 2122194687 10.191.1.117 57105 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2122129151 192.168.59.1 57106 typ host generation 0
```

Foundations are

```
1174096638
2999745851
```

Comment: For a particular candidate, how can i get foundation? what is 1 after the foundation value?

Comment: I think that you can retrieve the foundation by parsing the SDP for each candidate. 

1 is the ID of a component. If you are using RTP, you should have two values. 1 for RTP, 2 for RTCP. You may read the RFC 5245 (page 19) which describes that.

Comment: In RFC 5245 (page 22), about foundation explained that it is a identifier, means we can choose the number as per our requirement? is it correct or not? and what is the generation 0 in your example?

Comment: AFAIK, nothing in the spec defines exactly the range of the ID. But for example, in Firefox you will have small IDs (0,2, etc.), but in Chrome IDs are bigger (1174096638, 2999745851, etc.)
Sorry, but according to [meta] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions), it would be better if you could next time open a new question rather than questioning/answering in the comments.